# Firefox on Linux : New Tabs show last visited web sites instead of "BLANK"

Tags: linux, firefox, centos, gnome

I just opened a new tab in firefox.
it is not blank

it is showing last visited web sites and etc.

how can i stop this ?

did firefox implement this new thing ? i just re-installed centos
and installed firefox.

my firefox version is: `17.0.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `about:config` in your address bar and navigate there. Type `browser.newtab.url` in the search box and change the value of this parameter to `about:blank` (Just double click the line to open the prompt). Now restart the browser. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean. That bugs me to. It's not very obvious, but there's a little button in the top right corner. Click that. Same thing if you ever want to switch back.